# Send an email using Firebase Cloud Functions in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I would like to send emails in my React Native using Firebase Cloud Functions. Users should be able to send an email for reporting issues/feedback in the app. I have created a text input and a button in my react native app. The user should be able to specify their issue/feedback in the text input box and when they press the button I will receive their response as an email in my gmail or hotmail account. Can I achieve this using onCreate in Firebase Cloud Functions? If so how can I achieve this? What would the onCreate method look like as well as the button function in react native? I am very new to react native and firebase cloud functions. Unfortunately, I haven't seen any links about this.

Thank you.

Please see below:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const email = functions.config().email_credentials.email;
const password = functions.config().email_credentials.password;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(`smtps://${email}:${password}@smtp.gmail.com`);

functions.database.ref('/feedbacks/{currentId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const feedback = snapshot.val().feedback;
      const name = snapshot.val().name;
      
      const mailOptions = {
        from: snapshot.val().email,
        replyTo: snapshot.val().email,
        to: functions.config().email_credentials.email,
        subject: `Feedback from `+name,
        html: feedback,
      };
      
          try {
               mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
          } catch(error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      
      return null;
      
  });
```

Realtime database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your cloud function could look like this:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
const { email, password } = functions.config().gmail;
const mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(
  `smtps://${email}:${password}@smtp.gmail.com`
);

export default functions.database
  .ref("/feedbacks/{uid}")
  .onCreate(async (eventSnapshot, context) => {
    const data = eventSnapshot.val();
    const { feedback } = data;

      const mailOptions = {
        from: functions.config().email_credentials.email,
        replyTo: functions.config().email_credentials.email,
        to: snapshot.val().email,
        subject: `Feedback from `+name,
        html: feedback,
      };

    await mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions);
    return null;
  });
```

Make sure to save your email credentials under the firebase cloud function configs and NOT in the code. If you put it anywhere in the code it could potentialy been read by someone in some time. This is very importand.

In your Gmail ensure "Unsercure Apps" are enabled. More about it [here](https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/).

Now if someon adds some data to the path `feeds` and email will be send.

Don't forget to deplyo your function with the configs.

Comment: Thank you. I also had to enable DisplayUnlockCaptcha in order to make it work. One thing that I noticed is that if I try to use a users email from my database in the from field e.g. snapshot.val().email it returns my gmail email address instead of the users email. But the replyTo field returns the users email address when I use snapshot.val().email. Do you know why? This is when using the simulator on my laptop.

Comment: Could you pls share some code with us to take a look on it. Maybe there is just a little typo or so.

Comment: Please see above. I see the users email from the realtime database in field replyTo but not in the from field in my inbox. My email is used instead in the from field.

Comment: You can't send a email from your users email. You can set the `replyTo` to any email but you are always sending the email `from` your email. In the `from` part you can put your Name and your Email. Any other email than yours will be ignored. If that would be posible we all could send emails from someone else ;)

Comment: I have updated the answer with the configs how they "should" be